# Match combinations of row values between 2 different data frames

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a `data.frame` with 16 different combinations of 4 different cell markers

```
combinations_df

     FITC Cy3 TX_RED Cy5
 a    0   0      0   0
 b    1   0      0   0
 c    0   1      0   0
 d    1   1      0   0
 e    0   0      1   0
 f    1   0      1   0
 g    0   1      1   0
 h    1   1      1   0
 i    0   0      0   1
 j    1   0      0   1
 k    0   1      0   1
 l    1   1      0   1
 m    0   0      1   1
 n    1   0      1   1
 o    0   1      1   1
 p    1   1      1   1
```

I have my "main" `data.frame` with 10 columns and thousands of rows.

```
> main_df
  a b FITC d Cy3 f TX_RED h Cy5 j
1 0 1    1 1   1 0      1 1   1 1
2 0 1    0 1   1 0      1 0   1 1
3 1 1    0 0   0 1      1 0   0 0
4 0 1    1 1   1 0      1 1   1 1
5 0 0    0 0   0 0      0 0   0 0
....
```

I want to use all the possible 16 combinations from `combinations_df` to compare with each row of `main_df`. Then I want to create a new `vector` to later `cbind` to `main_df` as column 11.

sample output

```
> phenotype
[1] "g" "i" "a" "p" "g"
```

I thought about doing a while loop within a for loop checking each `combinations_df` row through each `main_df` row.

Sounds like it could work, but I have close to 1 000 000 rows in `main_df`, so I wanted to see if anybody had a better idea.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I want to compare `combinations_df` only to columns 3,5,7,9 from `main_df`. They have the same name, but it might not be that obvious.

EDIT: Changin the sample data output, since no "t" should be present

Comment: what if you concatenate the 4 cell marker columns in each df and then do a match or merge using the new concatenated column

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you @emilliman5 , I'm relatively new to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dplyr` solution is outrageously simple. First you need to put `phenotype` in `combinations_df` as an explicit variable like this:

```
#   phenotype FITC Cy3 TX_RED Cy5
#1          a    0   0      0   0
#2          b    1   0      0   0
#3          c    0   1      0   0
#4          d    1   1      0   0
# etc
```

`dplyr` lets you join on multiple variables, so from here it's a one-liner to look up the phenotypes.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(main_df, combinations_df, by=c("FITC", "Cy3", "TX_RED", "Cy5"))

#  a b FITC d Cy3 f TX_RED h Cy5 j phenotype
#1 0 1    1 1   1 0      1 1   1 1         p
#2 0 1    0 1   1 0      1 0   1 1         o
#3 1 1    0 0   0 1      1 0   0 0         e
#4 0 1    1 1   1 0      1 1   1 1         p
#5 0 0    0 0   0 0      0 0   0 0         a
```

I originally thought you'd have to concatenate columns with `tidyr::unite` but this was not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Its not very elegant but this method works just fine. There are no loops in loops here so it should run just fine. Might trying to match using the dataframe rows and do away with the loops all together but this was just the fastest way I could figure it out. You might look at packages `plyr` or `data.table`. Very powerful packages for this kind of thing.

```
            main_text=NULL
            for(i in 1:length(main_df[,1])){
            main_text[i]<-paste(main_df[i,3],main_df[i,5],main_df[i,7],main_df[i,9],sep="")
            }
            comb_text=NULL
            for(i in 1:length(combinations_df[,1])){
            comb_text[i]<-paste(combinations_df[i,1],combinations_df[i,2],combinations_df[i,3],combinations_df[i,4],sep="")
            }

            rownames(combinations_df)[match(main_text,comb_text)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? My results are different than yours as there is no "t" in the combination_df. You could do it without assigning a new column to if you wanted. This is mainly for illustrative purposes.

```
combination_df <- read.table("Documents/comb.txt.txt", header=T)
main_df <- read.table("Documents/main.txt", header=T)

main_df
combination_df
main_df$key <- do.call(paste0, main_df[,c(3,5,7,9)])
combination_df$key <- do.call(paste0, combination_df)

rownames(combination_df)[match(main_df$key, combination_df$key)]
```

Comment: Ha, besides the `do.call` are answers are basically identical. Great minds think alike :D . Really need to get out of the habit of using for loops. Things like `lapply`, `do.call`, etc just look so much nicer.

Comment: good catch! will fix the "t" I just tried to generate a random sample of letters from a to p, but obviously I didn't...