# Creating a new column based on formula using list of names

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I've been able to find lots of answers for how to create a new column based on numeric formulas, but not names.

I have a melted dataframe for which I need to create a new column showing the category into which the variable falls. This is a section of my current dataframe:

```
   Year Type        variable     value
1  2016    T Agrostis.canina         6
2  2016    R Agrostis.canina         2
3  2016    Q Agrostis.canina         0
4  2016    T Carex.nigra             0
5  2016    R Carex.nigra             9
6  2016    Q Carex.nigra             3
7  2015    T Agrostis.canina         0
8  2015    R Agrostis.canina         2
9  2015    Q Agrostis.canina         0
10 2015    T Carex.nigra             6
11 2015    R Carex.nigra             0
12 2015    Q Carex.nigra             5
```

I have lists of variable names that come under each category saved in the work environment - I would like to use these to create the new column as there are a lot of variable names! Ideally the dataframe would look something like this:

```
   Year Type        variable     value    veg.type
1  2016    T Agrostis.canina         6    Graminoid
2  2016    R Agrostis.canina         2    Graminoid
3  2016    Q Agrostis.canina         0    Graminoid
4  2016    T Carex.nigra             0    Dwarf.shrub
5  2016    R Carex.nigra             9    Dwarf.shrub
6  2016    Q Carex.nigra             3    Dwarf.shrub
7  2015    T Agrostis.canina         0    Graminoid
8  2015    R Agrostis.canina         2    Graminoid
9  2015    Q Agrostis.canina         0    Graminoid
10 2015    T Carex.nigra             6    Dwarf.shrub
11 2015    R Carex.nigra             0    Dwarf.shrub
12 2015    Q Carex.nigra             5    Dwarf.shrub
```

I tried using within and ifelse, but I think I'm missing a key part of it as nothing has worked yet.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Each veg.type is basically a subset of various variables ie.

`Dwarf.shrub <- c("Calluna.vulgaris", "Empetrum.nigrum", "Erica.cinerea"...)
 Graminoid <- c("Agrostis.canina", "Deschampsia.flexuosa", "Holcus.lanatus"...)`
etc.

This means that I want lots of variables to come out with the same veg.type. I hope that this clarifies things a little.

Comment: Is there a key you use to join the data? Check ?merge in basic R or. left_join in dplyr which i suggest most for data manipulation

Comment: on what basis are you assigning values to the veg.type column?

Comment: I have lists or a dataframe with variables under each veg.type lists are (eg):
`Dwarf.shrub <- c("Calluna.vulgaris", "Empetrum.nigrum", "Erica.cinerea"...)
Graminoid <- c("Agrostis.canina", "Deschampsia.flexuosa", "Holcus.lanatus"...)`
etc.
As you can see there are multiple variables under each veg.type - more than 3 like I've shown. `merge` and `left_join` don't work as shown below for what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a second data frame that will be used as a lookup and then `left_join()` it to your main data frame. `stack()` converts the list directly to a stacked data frame.

```
df2 <- stack(list(Dwarf.Shrub=c("Carex.nigra", "Empetrum.nigrum"), Graminoid=c("Agrostis.canina", "Deschampsia.flexuosa"))) 

#                values         ind
#1          Carex.nigra Dwarf.Shrub
#2      Empetrum.nigrum Dwarf.Shrub
#3      Agrostis.canina   Graminoid
#4 Deschampsia.flexuosa   Graminoid
```

Now join with `dplyr` giving the variable names of the key in both data frames.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df2, by=c("variable" = "values"))

#   Year Type        variable value    veg.type
#1  2016    T Agrostis.canina     6   Graminoid
#2  2016    R Agrostis.canina     2   Graminoid
#3  2016    Q Agrostis.canina     0   Graminoid
#4  2016    T     Carex.nigra     0 Dwarf Shrub
# etc
```

Comment: I have lists for each veg.type in my Environment, or I can use a dataframe of them - there are multiple variables that are in each veg.type, not just one as is shown on the dataframe that I provided. I don't think I can `merge` or `left_join` dataframes like that.

Comment: You can join by more than one variable, if that's what you mean. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40185522/4477364) for example. It sounds like you want to make a lookup data frame from your lists and join by multiple variables.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. I have left a comment above that might help. 
Basically each veg.type is a subset of the variables and I have lists of the variables under each veg.tye eg:
`Dwarf.shrub <- c("Calluna.vulgaris", "Empetrum.nigrum", "Erica.cinerea"...) Graminoid <- c("Agrostis.canina", "Deschampsia.flexuosa", "Holcus.lanatus"...) `
Maybe I need to subset the data first.

Comment: OK. How about making your lookup df using your lists and `stack()`: `df2 <- stack(list(Dwarf.Shrub=c("Carex.nigra", "Empetrum.nigrum"),
     Graminoid=c("Agrostis.canina", "Deschampsia.flexuosa")))` then `left_join(df, df2, by=c("variable" = "values"))`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked! my problem is that I had the lookup dataframe in wide format rather than long. I changed it using `tidyr` `gather`. Thank you for your help!! :-D

Comment: Glad you got there. Yes `tidyr::gather()` can also be used in place of `stack()`. I have updated my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to use a look-up table (and you don't need to `merge`):

```
lookup <- list(Agrostis.canina="Graminoid", 
               Carex.nigra="Dwarf.shrub")
df$value <- lookup[df$variable]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
output.df <- merge(df1, df2, by="variable", all.x=T)
```

The all.x parameter means you keep all rows in df1. You could also do all.y if you wanted or leave it out entirely for only intersecting rows. Additionally, if you would like to merge on multiple columns, you can expand the "by" parameter with:

```
by=c("param 1 name","param 2 name",...)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post my solution:

I used `left_join` like @Joe suggested. I had a "lookup" dataframe of the different values that came under each variable, but my original dataframe was in wide format rather than long. I used the `gather` function in  `tidyr` to create a long format, which meant that I could transform the dataframe without keeping some id variable columns the same like it seems you need to in the `reshape2` `melt` function.

Thanks again everyone for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Do consider accepting one of the answers and upvoting all that happened to be useful... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the tick was how you accept an answer! (oops)